# wrong number of arguments in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arguments

I need to randomly generate a name and capitalization.
I am getting the wrong number of arguments error

" main.rb:21:in `random_both': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2) (ArgumentError) from main.rb:26:in` ' "

And I don't understand the error enough to know what I need to fix here.
I would just like to know where this is going wrong.

I'm not looking for the answer necessarily but a push in the right direction would be lovely...

*note I can only amend

```
    def random_both(random_name, random_case)
     [random_name, random_case].sample
    end
```

Comment: Some clarification would be helpful. What is `random_both` supposed to do / return? And how is it related to `random_name` and `random_case`?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is pretty clear: you defined `random_both` with 2 parameters, but you are passing 0 arguments when you call it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass `random_both` two arguments. You’re currently passing zero arguments, like this: `random_both()`. But just passing `random_both` two arguments won’t work either because you’re calling `random_case` from `random_both` and `random_case` also takes an argument.

Comment: So I have since updated to remove the 2 params and now i get the following. Is the code i've now written, messing with the code on line 15?

$ruby main.rb
        main.rb:15:in `random_case': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) (ArgumentError)
         from main.rb:21:in `random_both'
         from main.rb:26:in `<main>'

Comment: `random_case` also takes one argument.

Comment: but I can't edit that. So how can I call them to random_both. that's what I don't understand. I am stumped at how to bring the existing methods into a new method when calling them doesn't seem to be allowed

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a misunderstanding of concepts.

```
def random_both(random_name, random_case)
 [random_name, random_case].sample
end
```

You are trying to use methods (random_name, random_case) as parameters.

Proceed to remove them from parameters and it should work.